# ActiViz.NET.x64 (v5.8.0): Unable to load DLL 'Kitware.VTK.vtkFiltering.Unmanaged.dll'

Tags: c#, .net, dll, wrapper, vtk

I'm trying to use the [VTK](http://www.vtk.org) with C# to read and write VTK/VTS files. I created a basic app, and I installed the 64-bit VTK .NET wrapper package which is called ActiViz.NET.x64 (v5.8.0).

The package installed without any problems, and I could access the Kitware.VTK namespace, but as soon as I try to create a VTK object, I got an unmanaged DLL loading error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Kitware.VTK.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'Kitware.VTK.vtkFiltering.Unmanaged.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I don't think that the exact code is relevant here, but I got the exception at the following line:

`vtkStructuredGrid structuredGrid = vtkStructuredGrid.New();`

I'm using Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2015, the target .NET Framework is 4.6.2 and I have ParaView 4.1 and 5.2 installed. The DLL in question is in the bin directory of the app, but I also tried to copy it to the Windows/System32 directory, the result is the same.

Is there a way to figure out what exactly the problem is with the dll loading?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [ActiViz product page](https://www.kitware.eu/product/activiz) you can see the following in the FAQ:

> **Does ActiViz 64 work with Visual Studio?**
>
> Visual Studio is a 32 bits
>   application, therefore 64 bits control does not work and you need the
>   32 bits version of ActiViz when using the designer within Visual
>   Studio. Usually, the 32 bits version is used to design and the 64 bits
>   version is used for the final compilation.

I also use VTK/ActiViz (C#) on Visual Studio, and it works fine when my program is targeting x86 platforms. However, if I target x64 platforms, the winforms control for the render window disappears, but I can still build the executable. So do this:

1) Install Activiz.NET.x86 from NuGet & target x86 platforms;

2) Create and debug your App;

3) Make a backup of the solution folder;

4) Install Activiz.NET.x64 from NuGet & target x64 platforms;

5) Don't open the designer because it will be buggy (all RenderWindowsControl disappear);

6) Build the solution (Release x64).

Answer (score 1):

So, first I wanted to know where exactly is my process looking for the missing DLL. I used [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) and its [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor).

[image]

I referenced VTK in my .NET library which I used in my self-hosted app. The self-hosted app was the start-up project, so the runtime looked for the missing DLL in the app's directory, not the library's, where it actually was.

After I copied the missing Kitware.VTK.vtkFiltering.Unmanaged.dll to that directory, Process Monitor confirmed that the DLL was read successfully, but I still got the same exception as before.

I compared the library's and the app's bin directories, and I figured that only the Kitware.mummy.Runtime.dll and Kitware.VTK.dll were copied there automatically. 
I copied all the other VTK DLLs to the app's bin, and then it finally worked.

The exception's error message wasn't detailed in the first place, but I think it is more likely a problem with the ActiViz.NET package.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy all dlls from Activiz Installation bin directory even you don't need to use in your code.
C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiViz.NET 5.8.0 OpenSource Edition\bin

Managed .Net DLL's is a wrapper for unmanaged VTK libraries. Mummy.dll is for this job.